# Spark driver unable to start in cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I am submitting jobs to Spark Cluster using SparkLauncher ~ which will start Spark driver on one of the worker nodes. But driver startup always fails with this exception appears 16 times:

```
level="WARN",threadName="main",logger="org.apache.spark.util.Utils",message="Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1."
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: the port number looks incorrect, you can change it through spark.driver.port

Comment: After I put in a random port for this value, it worked. Thanks! It's strange that according to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html "spark.driver.port (random)" should be random but it kept on picking 0. I didn't set it for sure.
Can you add your comment as answer, so that it can be accepted?

Comment: Added, thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, there was some other error and I thought Driver start error went away by using this property, but it did't. I am setting properties on SparkLauncher as below but same error as in question:
 .setConf("spark.driver.cores", "2")
 .setConf("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
 .setConf("spark.driver.port", "5556")

Comment: Also to mention, this is a standalone cluster

Comment: Also https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#configuring-ports-for-network-security it says:
Akka-based. Set to "0" to choose a port randomly.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out. If you set environment variable SPARK_LOCAL_IP = 0.0.0.0 from the machine where you're launching the job from, it seems to fix it. As per documentation, it'll choose a random port for driver to run on any worker node in the cluster. As per comment by @yyny, if you wish to fix the port of driver, you can use "spark.driver.port".

Answer (score 0):

he port number looks incorrect, you can change it through spark.driver.port